# Too big tin for meringue cake recipe. How to solve?

Tags: cake, meringue, recipe-scaling

So I have this recipe for a hazelnut meringue cake. It asks for an 18cm tin. However, I only have a 24cm tin. I went to the shop today but they do not have a 18cm tin. So i guess there are several other possible options.

I could make more of the recipe using the 24cm tin. However the surface of the meringue will be about 2.25x the meringue then when using the 18 cm tin. So does that mean I have to use over 2 times the amount of ingredients? Or won't that work?

An other option is not using a tin at all. I actually thought that you do not need a tin for making meringue. So I can just draw an 18cm circle and put the mixture on the baking tray. Will this work or not? I have very little experience with meringue so far.

Two meringues will be made with (original recipe for 18 cm tin):
-3 egg whits
-175 golden caster sugar
-85 grams chopped roasted hazelnuts.

Which idea will work? Or is there a better idea?

-edit-

So I draw a circle and put the maringue mixture on. It worked out very well!
The cake turned out delicious. 
Thanks for the feed back.

Comment: Nice to hear the cake turned out fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions will work.

If you are making more mering, then make sure the thickness of the meringue layer in stays the same as for the small tin. If you scale the recipe correctly this happens automatically.

I think your math is off though. The area of your 24 inch tin is only 1.77 times larger than the 18 inch pan.

Assuming your pan is round: The area of the large pan is pi*24^2 and the area of the small is pi*18^2 the ratio is therefore pi*24^2 / pi*18^2 = 24^2 / 18^2 = (24/18)^2 = 1.77 .

If your pan is square the (almost) same computation will give the same result.

Comment: Woops I took 8 and 12 in stand of 9 and 12. That is really stupid! 64/144. However I'm going to draw a circle anyway now. Thank you for the feed back!